# How to reset a SurveyMonkey long-lived access token

Tags: access-token, surveymonkey

We have a Survey Monkey custom application that uses OAuth to query our real (non-Developer) Survey Monkey account and pull back survey results. I would like to reset the OAuth Access Token for security purposes, as we recently had a developer leave the company who worked on the custom application. I went into the real Survey Monkey account and removed the link, and then went back to the developer account and linked it back from the API Console. But it just re-generated the same access token we had before. Is there a way to get it to generate a new access token?

Thank you.

Comment: I would email api-support@surveymonkey.com about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miles Cederman-Haysom was right. I emailed api-support@surveymonkey, and they created a new API key for me and deleted the old one once I had confirmed that the new one was working.